# Parsing long string in R

Tags: r, parsing, nlp

I have a data frame which contains rows by date. One column, `text` contains a long string (text of municipal council motions) with the following format:

-> Number. (eg 1.)

-> string (eg Motion to get squirrels banned)

-> the word Councilor or Mayor + a Name (eg Councilor Obama)

-> Number. (eg 2.)

-> string (eg Action on standardizing calendars)

-> the word Councilor or Mayor + a Name (eg Mayor Biden)

etc

Such as in the below reprex:

```
n <- 3
dat <- data.frame(id=c("1","2","3"), 
                  date=c("2020-12-26","2020-12-31","2021-01-31"),
                  text=c("1. Increasing Public Access to Information About False Creek South  Councillor Dennings submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  2. Turning Construction Hoard ing into a Canvass for Public Art in Vancouver  Councillor Pikachu submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  Council Meeting Minutes, March 9, 2021 34  3. A Pl an to Significantly Reduce the Citys Permitting Backlog  Mayor Dominato submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. ",
                         "1. Doing something good for health  Councillor Horse submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  2. Doing something for the good of the kids  Mayor Bowser submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. ", 
                         "1. Finding a way to make an impact  Councillor Nimby bmitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  2. Doing something for farmers  Councillor Biscoff submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. 3. Funding a park for puppies  Councillor AnimalLover submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. 4. Providing tea for all students  Councillor Shumba submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion."))
```

I'd like to parse the text column so that for each row, the number and the sentence following it is extracted and put into a separate column, and the Councilor or Mayor that submitted the motion is saved into a third column, and so on for each number afterwards. The data frame would look like this reprex:

```
n <- 3
dat <- data.frame(id=c("1","2","3"), 
                  date=c("2020-12-26","2020-12-31","2021-01-31"),
                  text=c("1. Increasing Public Access to Information About False Creek South  Councillor Dennings submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  2. Turning Construction Hoard ing into a Canvass for Public Art in Vancouver  Councillor Pikachu ",
                         "1. Doing something good for health  Councillor Horse submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. ", 
                         "1. Finding a way to make an impact  Councillor Nimby bmitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion.  2. Doing something for farmers  Councillor Biscoff submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. 3. Funding a park for puppies  Councillor AnimalLover submitted a notice of Council Members motion on the above -noted matter. The motion may be placed on the Council meeting agenda of March 30, 2021, as a Council Members Motion. "),
                  Motion1= c('1. Increasing Public Access to Information About False Creek South',
                  '1. Doing something good for health', 
                  '1. Finding a way to make an impact'),
                  Motion1_Submitter= c('Councillor Dennings',
                                       'Councillor Horse',
                                       'Councillor Nimby'),
                  Motion2 = c('2. Turning Construction Hoard ing into a Canvass for Public Art in Vancouver',
                  'NA',
                  '2. Doing something for farmers'),
                  Motion2_Submitter = c('Councillor Pikachu',
                                        'NA',
                                        ' Councillor Biscoff'),
                  Motion3= c('NA', 'NA', '3. Funding a park for puppies.'),
                  Motion3_Submitter = c('NA', 'NA', '  Councillor AnimalLover'))
```

Is there a package or way to do this in R? Would it be easier to do in Python?

TIA!

Comment: getting started `sp <- strsplit(dat$text, '(?<= )(?=\\d\\.|(Councillor|Mayor)|((su)?bmitted))', perl = TRUE); rapply(sp, function(X) Filter(function(x) grepl('^(\\d\\.|Councillor|Mayor)', x), X), how = 'list')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(Motion = str_extract_all(text, "\\d\\..*?(?=\\s+Councillor|Mayor)"),
         Motion_Submitter = str_extract_all(text, "(Councillor|Mayor)\\s\\w+\\b")) %>% 
  unnest(c(Motion, Motion_Submitter))
```

this returns

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 5
  id    date       text                                    Motion                         Motion_Submitter  
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>                                   <chr>                          <chr>             
1 1     2020-12-26 "1. Increasing Public Access to Inform~ "1. Increasing Public Access ~ Councillor Dennin~
2 1     2020-12-26 "1. Increasing Public Access to Inform~ "2. Turning Construction Hoar~ Councillor Pikachu
3 1     2020-12-26 "1. Increasing Public Access to Inform~ "3. A Pl an to Significantly ~ Mayor Dominato    
4 2     2020-12-31 "1. Doing something good for health  C~ "1. Doing something good for ~ Councillor Horse  
5 2     2020-12-31 "1. Doing something good for health  C~ "2. Doing something for the g~ Mayor Bowser      
6 3     2021-01-31 "1. Finding a way to make an impact  C~ "1. Finding a way to make an ~ Councillor Nimby  
7 3     2021-01-31 "1. Finding a way to make an impact  C~ "2. Doing something for farme~ Councillor Biscoff
8 3     2021-01-31 "1. Finding a way to make an impact  C~ "3. Funding a park for puppie~ Councillor Animal~
9 3     2021-01-31 "1. Finding a way to make an impact  C~ "4. Providing tea for all stu~ Councillor Shumba
```

From here you could use

```r
 dat %>% 
  mutate(Motion = str_extract_all(text, "\\d\\..*?(?=\\s+Councillor|Mayor)"),
         Motion_Submitter = str_extract_all(text, "(Councillor|Mayor)\\s\\w+\\b")) %>% 
  unnest(c(Motion, Motion_Submitter)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn,
              values_from = c(Motion, Motion_Submitter),
              names_glue = "{.value}{rn}") %>%
  ungroup()
```

to bring it into a wide format

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 11
  id    date       text   Motion1 Motion2 Motion3 Motion4 Motion_Submitte~ Motion_Submitte~ Motion_Submitte~
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 1     2020-12-26 "1. I~ 1. Inc~ "2. Tu~ "3. A ~ NA      Councillor Denn~ Councillor Pika~ Mayor Dominato  
2 2     2020-12-31 "1. D~ 1. Doi~ "2. Do~  NA     NA      Councillor Horse Mayor Bowser     NA              
3 3     2021-01-31 "1. F~ 1. Fin~ "2. Do~ "3. Fu~ 4. Pro~ Councillor Nimby Councillor Bisc~ Councillor Anim~
# ... with 1 more variable: Motion_Submitter4 <chr>
```